# Automatic namespaced urls for non-admin models in Rails admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `User` that I want to manage in the admin interface.
The admin interface routes look like

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

When I create a link in a view like `link_to 'Show', @user`, I get the
error `undefined method 'user_path'`.

How do I automatically have that url turn into `admin_user_path` (i.e. `/admin/users/:id`
instead of `/users/:id`)

Currently I am having to do this everywhere (index view, show view, edit, form url etc.):
`link_to 'Show', admin_user_url(@user)`

Answer (score 0):

To link to namespaced routes pass an array:

```
link_to 'Show', [:admin, @user]
```

If what you instead want is to nest the routes under `/admin` without adding the admin prefix to the route helpers use `scope` instead of `namespace`:

```
scope :admin, module: :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

---

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    users GET    /admin/users(.:format)          admin/users#index
          POST   /admin/users(.:format)          admin/users#create
 new_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)      admin/users#new
edit_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) admin/users#edit
     user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#show
          PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#update
          PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#update
          DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#destroy
```

This would make sense if you only have `/admin/users` routes and not a `/users` route the represents the resource differently - in that case use `link_to 'Show', [:admin, @user]` to disambiguate.